# ASP.Net Dynamic Font and Colour Customisation

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently trying to design an asp.net site that allows the user to change their colours. 
The specific example is to say have the company site admin able to customise the colours to maintain branding for all users. 
I have found a couple of similar posts on SO, see here: [ASP.NET MVC - Dynamic Style Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868616/asp-net-mvc-dynamic-style-sheet) and here: [Dynamically generate CSS file from database in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286010/dynamically-generate-css-file-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc)
However, given the age of these answers, i wonder if there's a better way to do this with the Razor engine/MVC 4/5? I would also like to be able to customise fonts for key pages (like login etc), which would be handled in the same way.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search term you are looking for is "theme engine". After doing a Google search, I came up with this:

- https://aspnetmvctheme.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32847/ASP-NET-MVC-Dynamic-Themes
- http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/186/using-the-themes-helper-in-razor-web-pages

Comment: Cheers, I realise the whole "google is your friend" but bit difficult when you dont know what to search, ill check these out now. Thanks